# What is the best combo of Mastermind?

Tags: elsword-online

I have Mastermind level 62 now and trying to PVP with other player. The best combo i use now is `Z>Z>Z (do uppercut and send opponent flying) > jump+forward+Z (catch flying opponent and do combo from beginning)`. But i have a problem while catching the flying opponent. It tends to loose and make the opponent drop to floor. Anyone have another combo for Mastermind?

Comment: it should have `elsword` tag. But i dont have enough reputation

Comment: Added a new tag called elsword-online and waiting for it to get approved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't play Mastermind but from what other players tell me, Mastermind literally has 4 or 5 viable combos in PvP, so you should stick to what works and do it.

- `ZZ→ ZZ→ ZZ→...`

  Basically hold `→` and tap `Z` twice.
- `ZZZ←←→ ZZZ←←→ ZZZ←←→...`

  Variation of the above. Good for pushing to the wall.
- `XX←←→ XX←←→ XX←←→...`

  Another good loop, which has really good range and can close in safely.
- `→→Z →→Z →→Z →→Z...`

  A really good pushing combo. Gives back a lot of mana.
- `→→↑X →↑X →↑X...`

  When you land after doing a `→→↑X` while holding `→`, you automatically go into dash, so you just have to do `↑X` at this point to do another `→→↑X`. This is a very useful combo if you have them against a wall because it has zero knockdown and you can keep looping this until they die. Use one of the pushing combos to get them to the wall, then use this.
- If you have launched your opponent and want to recatch them, you have to do what's called a *fastfall* jump `Z` or `X`. It's a bit tricky, and you do that by doing `↑↓Z` or `↑↓X`. That way you land faster and are able to catch them with a `Z` before they fall. Just make sure you let go of `↓` before you hit the ground, else you will go into a landing animation and fail to catch the opponent.

Comment: yes, i agree about the second combo, its best for comboing your enemy. all character have that combo, but difficult to use. and as for second from last, you must have jump speed very high to do that. i dont wanna sacrifice my other stats just for jump speed

Comment: You don't really need jump speed for it. In fact, the lower the jump speed the better, since you want to be as low as possible while doing `→→↑X`. You do need attack speed though.